# Rails uniqueness validation fails for no reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, validates-uniqueness-of

I have an scope-based uniqueness validation in place: `validates :company_standard, uniqueness: { scope: :company_id }` on a Rails Model `X`.

On the attached screenshot I am trying to create a new object of class `X` for that company via a form (=the standard process), not having the `company_standard` field or any other boolean field activated.

Still, the saving fails with a `uniqueness` validation error on `company_standard` (see screenshot).

A separate object of class `X` for this company exists with the company_standard=true in the database (I double-checked the form on correct naming). Updating the existing record and setting the boolean field to false seems to also fail with the same validation error.

No clue why this is failing. Looks like unexpected behavior to me.

[image: The validation error on the form]

Update after comment from @mechnicov:
**Model**

```
    class MeanOfPayment < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :company
      has_many :in_payments
      has_many :out_payments
      has_many :bank_statements, dependent: :destroy
    
      validates :company_standard, uniqueness: { scope: :company_id }
    
      before_validation :remove_spaces
    
      def balance
        ...
      end
    
      def account_name
        ...
      end
    
      private
    
      def remove_spaces
        ...
      end
end
```

**Controller**

```
class Home::MeanOfPaymentsController < HomeController
  def index
    @title = t('titles.mean_of_payments.index')
    @mean_of_payments = current_company.mean_of_payments
  end

  def show
    @title = t('titles.mean_of_payments.show')
    @mean_of_payment = current_company.mean_of_payments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @title = t('titles.mean_of_payments.new')
    company_id = Company.find(params[:company_id]).id
    @mean_of_payment = MeanOfPayment.new(company_id: company_id)
  end

  def create
    fix_number(mean_of_payment_params[:balance_at_date])
    @mean_of_payment = (mean_of_payment_params[:type].constantize).new(mean_of_payment_params)
    if @mean_of_payment.save
      redirect_to home_company_mean_of_payments_path(Company.find(params[:company_id])), notice: t('mean_of_payment.notifications.create_successfully')
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @title = t('titles.mean_of_payments.edit')
    @mean_of_payment = MeanOfPayment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    fix_number(mean_of_payment_params[:balance_at_date])
    @mean_of_payment = MeanOfPayment.find(params[:id])
    if @mean_of_payment.update(mean_of_payment_params)
      redirect_to home_company_mean_of_payments_path(Company.find(params[:company_id])), notice: t('mean_of_payment.notifications.update_successfully')
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    mean_of_payment = MeanOfPayment.find(params[:id])
    company_id = mean_of_payment.company.id
    mean_of_payment.update!(marked_deleted: true)
    redirect_to home_company_mean_of_payments_path(company_id: company_id), method: :destroy, notice: t('mean_of_payment.notifications.delete_successfully')
  end

  private

  def mean_of_payment_params
    validation =  if params[:bank_account].present?
                    params.require(:bank_account)
                  elsif params[:cash_counter].present?
                    params.require(:cash_counter)
                  elsif params[:mean_of_payment].present?
                    params.require(:mean_of_payment)
                  else
                    raise "Zahlungsmethode muss im Controller eingeführt werden!"
                  end

    validation.permit(
        :account_name,
        :account_number,
        :balance_at_date,
        :balance_date,
        :bank_name,
        :bank_number,
        :company_id,
        :company_standard,
        :for_out_invoice,
        :owner,
        :primary_debitable,
        :type,
    )

  end
end
```

**View 1 - new**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8 offset-2">
    <%= link_to t('common.buttons.back'), home_company_mean_of_payments_path %>
    <h1>
      <%= t('mean_of_payment.new.title') %>
    </h1>
    <%= render 'form', path: home_company_mean_of_payments_path(id: current_company.id) %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**View 2 - form**

```
<%= simple_form_for @mean_of_payment, url: path do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :company_id, value: current_user.accounting_company.id %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-content">
          <% if @mean_of_payment.errors.any? %>
            <div id="error_explanation">
              <h4><%= t('activerecord.errors.models.mean_of_payment.prohibited_save', count: @mean_of_payment.errors.count) %></h4>
              <ul>
                <% @mean_of_payment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                  <li><%= message %></li>
                <% end %>
              </ul>
            </div>
          <% end %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :type %>
            <%= f.select :type, options_for_mean_of_payment_general, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :bank_name %>
            <%= f.text_field :bank_name, class: 'form-control w-50' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :bank_number %>
            <%= f.text_field :bank_number, class: 'form-control w-50' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :account_name %>
            <%= f.text_field :account_name, class: 'form-control w-50'%>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :account_number %>
            <%= f.text_field :account_number, class: 'form-control w-50' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :owner %>
            <%= f.text_field :owner, class: 'form-control w-50' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :balance_at_date %>
            <%= f.text_field :balance_at_date, class: 'form-control w-50' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :balance_date %>
            <%= f.input :balance_date, as: :date, html5: true, class: 'form-control w-50', label: false %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :company_standard %>
            <%= f.check_box :company_standard, class: 'form-control w-50' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :for_out_invoice %>
            <%= f.check_box :for_out_invoice, class: 'form-control w-50' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :primary_debitable %>
            <%= f.check_box :primary_debitable, class: 'form-control w-50' %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.submit t('common.buttons.create_or_modify'), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Instead of your picture it's better to add log, code of the models, controller, view etc.

Comment: @mechnicov just edited the post with all the code pieces! The error message comes from the locales but is the uniqueness validation error

Comment: does it fail on both create and update?

Comment: @Les Nightingill
it fails on new and update for the object which where the uniqueness validation applies (= uniquenly true). Other existing objects can be updated (where created before this new was failing)

Answer (score 1):

> Updating the existing record and setting the boolean field to false seems to also fail with the same validation error.

This strongly implies that your DB contains another record for that `company_id` with `company_standard=false`. Please check this from a rails console with something like:

```rb
> MeanOfPayment.where company_id: the_company_id
```

Please show this by copy/pasting those console commands and responses to the question. If there's only one record then the next obvious suspect here is your `remove_spaces` call, please add the code for that to your question.

Comment: and if there is a  record with nil in db and saving nil - it will also fail the uniqness

Comment: I will check later but there are other records in DB with company_standard = nil for sure in DB.

Comment: All records set to '''company_standard: false'''.
But an issue still exists:
New '''company''' > '''create/update''' a '''mean_of_payments''' works with '''company_standard: false/true'''.

But a 2nd '''mean_of_payment''' fails the the uniqueness validation independent how I set '''company_standard''' on 2nd record.

This should fail when 1st '''mean_of_payment.company_standard: true''' and I am trying to set '''true''' on the 2nd record.

But if 2nd record has '''company_standard: false''' or the 1st record has '''company_standard: false''' this should work flawlessly.

Comment: @smathy - dont get your question. There should be the possibility to have multiple records but it should be uniquely true. Can the uniqueness maybe not be applied to boolean because both records have a value? '''True''' or '''false'''?

Comment: Just got an idea: The '''validator''' might be wrong overall. It is checking '''uniquness'''.

I wanted to secure the attribute '''company_standard''' is set only once to '''true'' the rest should be logically ''false'''. Uniqueness validation probably fails on booleans being set to '''false''' not being '''nil'''. I think now, that uniqueness validation shouldnt be used for boolean attribbutes validating one being true. If I will test and hopefully answer my own question if it works :-)

Comment: It seems like you might not have realized what uniqueness was. Yes, obviously `false` is a value too. So with that validation in place you would have only been able to have two records for each `company_id`, one with `company_standard` set to `true` and one with it set to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `company_id` from `params[:company_id]`

```rb
company_id = Company.find(params[:company_id]).id
@mean_of_payment = MeanOfPayment.new(company_id: company_id)
```

only to override it in your form

```rb
f.hidden_field :company_id, value: current_user.accounting_company.id
```

which I assume stays the same, regardless of params.

Also your form url seems a little suspect:

```rb
home_company_mean_of_payments_path(id: current_company.id)
```

Which gives you `params[:id]`. Doesn't that imply `mean_of_payment.id` for that controller? `home_company_mean_of_payments` - plural, so `id` seems out of place, you're creating you don't have an id yet.

Look at your logs and see what PARAMETERS your're submitting. Hard to tell what company_id you expect to have vs what gets submitted:

```
params[:id]
params[:company_id]
params[:mean_of_payment][:company_id] # this is what you're using for your model

current_user.accounting_company.id    # are these different from params[:company_id]
current_company.id                    #
```

Comment: All records set to '''company_standard: false'''.
But an issue still exists:
New '''company''' > '''create/update''' a '''mean_of_payments''' works with '''company_standard: false/true'''.

But a 2nd '''mean_of_payment''' fails the the uniqueness validation independent how I set '''company_standard''' on 2nd record.

This should fail when 1st '''mean_of_payment.company_standard: true''' and I am trying to set '''true''' on the 2nd record.

But if 2nd record has '''company_standard: false''' or the 1st record has '''company_standard: false''' this should work flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I had a wrong understanding of an `uniquness` validator (took 2 days to find out...).

**WRONG**
I thought it ensures an attribute is set only once to true (i.e. my thinking: 'uniquely').

**CORRECT**
But it actually checks if the attribute is present in general. So `false` is also present in this case i.e. `not nil` (didnt double check the Rails code if it checks for nil though). Sounds stupid looking at it now :-).

**So in my case**

A `company has_many mean_of_payments` but just one with boolean attribute `company_standard` being `true`.

Uniqueness validation of course didnt work since other `mean_of_payments` had `company_standard` set to `false`.

I needed a validator which checks the max occurences to max 1. Didnt find something standard so I wrote my own custom validator which does the trick:

**Custom validation using `validates_with` on the model**

```
class MeanOfPayment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
...
  validates_with UniqueCompanyStandardValidator, if: :company_standard
end
```

**With custom validator class:**

```
class UniqueCompanyStandardValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    mops = MeanOfPayment.where(company_id: record.company_id, company_standard: true).pluck(:id) # looks in DB not at the current record
    if mops.length > 0 # DB shouldnt have a company_standard: true
      record.errors[:base] << I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.mean_of_payment.attributes.company_standard.taken')
    end
  end
end
```

**Summary**

1. The validator is only called if the attribute is set to `true`
2. Checks DB if `mean_of_payment.company_standard` with Attribute `true` exist already

This whole thing occured to me today at 11 am after reading all your comments! So many thanks for this! Thanks for your indirect help! :-)